# Is it possible to render react application or components with only webpack compiled files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Once webpack compiles all files and dependencies into the JS and CSS, is it possible to only use these files to render the application or individual components?

I've copied the files generated by webpack and referenced them in an html file along with loading in react via CDN

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="onboard-9699e581.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./application-164084cc642ac889b814.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./onboard-d3392dbee6550206507b.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Perhaps I'm missing the point of what webpack does, but I'm assuming the components that I created in jsx files would all be compiled into JS and now live in the `./onboard-d3392dbee6550206507b.js` file? That would allow me to reference them and allow them to be rendered via `reactDOM.render?`

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. Still trying to wrap my head around this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you pack everything into a single JavaScript file that runs when the page renders. The React code attaches to whatever element you've pre-defined (in most cases, this will be div#app) and builds the DOM according to all of your JSX and other logic.

The JSX isn't standalone code to be added in one by one - you've already built a whole app that 'just runs'. JSX is just a fancy way to write HTML that can also include scripts, and allows for nice features like writing multiline HTML fragments for ease of reading.

Work through [this example](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75) and see if it makes more sense afterwards. Pay particular attention to when they run the application out of the `dist` folder, which is the equivalent of running the production version of the site (after webpack).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, that's the way it is, what webpack does is transpile all your jsx files and bundles those in an output js file which will be called by the index.html(that is why the div with id="root") as a script tag. That's because most of web browser can't read yet jsx. Also it minifies the code in the process to make it more light weight which means faster loading.